# Laravel Passport Custom Hashing Mechanism

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I'm currently building an application (using Laravel) that works along with a larger application (Zend 1.x).

I'm using Laravel passport for API authentication. I need to change the Laravel Passport default hashing mechanism to the Zend hashing in order to have the authentication work.

Can someone point me to an API or something I need to override to get this running? I prefer to not edit the core Laravel Passport code.

I've seen suggestions of creating a custom user provider and modifying the `validateCredentials()` method but these are all for core Laravel.

I'm already using findForPassport method in the User class to override the username field.

```
public function findForPassport($username)
{
    return $this->where('email', $username)->first();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone wondering, you can override 2 methods (maybe more) in the User class to handle customizing Laravel Passport authentication:

```
/**
 * Override the field which is used for username in the authentication
 */
public function findForPassport($username)
{
    return $this->where('email', $username)->first();
}

/**
 * Add a password validation callback 
 * 
 * @param type $password
 * @return boolean Whether the password is valid
 */
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    $hasher = new HSAUserHasher(); // Or whomever does your hashing

    $result = $hasher->create_hash($password, $this->salt);
    $hashedPassword = $result['password'];

    return $hashedPassword == $this->password;
}
```

Thanks to @redviking on the Laravel slack forums (https://larachat.slack.com) for helping me towards the answer.